# How to delete the contents of a USB Stick in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, rm

I'm not looking to format the stick at all, but rather to iterate through the files deleting them all (though after typing 'iterate through' I can sense a Python script coming along.

So far I've been doing `rm filename1` `rm filename2` `rm filename3` etc, is there a way to just 'rm -all' while on in the root of the USB drive?

Comment: `man` is your friend.

Comment: I tried this before posting -- couldn't figure it out.

Comment: rm filename*
or
rm | grep filename

Answer (score 17):

Yes:

```
rm -rf *
```

**Be carefull where you are when you run this** it will delete *everything* from the current directory and all subdirectories.

If you only want to delete files, and no directories use:

```
rm *
```

As @DanielAndersson very correctly pointed out in the comments, this will not delete hidden files and directories (those beginning with a `.`). To delete those as well do

```
rm -rf * .*
```

This will give an error about not being able to delete `.` and `..` (the current and parent directories respectively). You can safely ignore that, `rm` will never delete these since they are protected by the POSIX standard (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/22222) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html)). If you don't want to see the error message you can specify that you only want to delete those dotfiles and folders whose `.` is followed by a non `.` character:

```
rm -rf * .[^.]*
```

Finally, if you want to delete all files in  the current directory and all subdirectories but **keep the directories**, do this:

```
find . -type f -delete
```

Comment: You're the man!  Thanks @terdon -- I would upvote but you need 15 rep :(

Comment: I'll remember September sixth as the first time in the history of the internet someone legitimately recommended executing `rm -rf *`.

Comment: @DaveMelia if you can't upvote, please at least accept the answer (the tickmark on the left) so the question can be marked as answered.

Comment: @MarcksThomas heh, true, true, might be the first time I've seen a legitimate use myself :).

Comment: One could note that hidden files and directories in the current directory won't be erased by `rm -rf *` (unless `dotglob` happens to be set).

Comment: @MarcksThomas, yeah, they defanged rm -rf a few years ago. it will prompt you if it detects you running 'rm -rf /' and ask if you are really really sure.

Comment: Oi, anyway this should cover most hidden files and directories: `rm -rf /path/to/directory/{*,.[A-Za-z0-9]*}`

Comment: @terdon, do **not** advocate `.*` it contains the parent directory via **..**

Comment: @justbrowsing true but that will just give an error message about not being able to delete `.` and `..`. I don't know if that is a GNU thing though so, I'll make that clear in the answer.

Comment: @justbrowsing I now [know](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/22222) that `rm` will never delete `.` and `..` so there is reason to worry about it.